# INNER JOIN on selection

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with the inner join. I need to filter the table before it will combine tables using inner join. The following code is of course wrong but I need something like this. Please help.

```
SELECT * FROM hotel LEFT OUTER JOIN (**hotel_table where hotel_table.id_offer=$id**) ON (hotel.id = hotel_table.id_hotel)
```

**Edit:**

Thanks for the fast answer. But I get an error: "Every derived table must have its own alias" My code:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   czajka_zakwaterowania 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
   SELECT * 
   FROM czajka_hotel_l 
   WHERE czajka_hotel_l.id_hotel=$id
   ) 
   ON (czajka_zakwaterowania.id = czajka_hotel_l.id_hotel)
```

How do I solve this?

This code displays the error: "Every derived table must have its own alias" I cant eliminate it.

Comment: Look again at gbn's answer. You are missing a name between the ")" and "ON" for the derived table.

Comment: Change the last two lines to this: `) CZAJKA_HOTEL_L ON (czajka_zakwaterowania.id = czajka_hotel_l.id_hotel)`. As you can see I added **czajka_hotel_l** between the ')' and 'ON'. This way I gave the derived table an Alias. gbn did this too in his answer, but you forgot it.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   hotel 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   hotel_table ON hotel.id = hotel_table.id_hotel AND hotel_table.id_offer=$id
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   hotel 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
   SELECT * 
   FROM hotel_table 
   WHERE hotel_table.id_offer=$id
   ) ht ON hotel.id = ht.id_hotel
```